# Realization Connector not allowed

Tags: enterprise-architect

I am trying to add a connector of type realization between a component and interface, it works fine in EA 10 but in EA 12 I am getting an error that "Realization is not valid from Component -> Interface".

Is it a bug or they don't allow it in version 12 anymore?

My code is

```
 private static void addRealization(Repository rep, Element sourceComponent)
    {
        EA.Element sourceComponentInterface = Database.Sql.getSourceComponentI(rep, sourceComponent.Name);
        EA.Connector connector = sourceComponent.Connectors.AddNew("", "Realisation");
        connector.SupplierID = sourceComponentInterface.ElementID;
        connector.Update();           
        sourceComponent.Connectors.Refresh();
        sourceComponentInterface.Connectors.Refresh();            
    }
```

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I though it was related with the option `Tools/Options/Links/Strict Connector Syntax` but actually I had not problem creating the connector (even with that checked). Hmm.

Comment: FWIW: The Refresh calls are superfluous and you should use Realization with 'z'  since the British spelling is deprecated. Which release number is it?

Comment: I am using version 12, and replacing s with z is still not working

Comment: I am using your book "Scripting EA"  and the update call is in there when we add a connector

Comment: 12 is the version. What is the release number?

Comment: 12.0.1208 is the exact version

Comment: Thanks for the reply unchecking Tools/Options/Links/Strict Connector Syntax worked :)

Comment: Consider upgrading EA. I tested with 1224 and had no issue with creation.

Comment: Hi thomas, I create a model using EA Scripting and I create interfaces and operations for each interface then I also add these interfaces in a composition diagram , how can I not show the operations in diagram in EA 12

Comment: Make it a new question and I might answer :-)

Comment: Here is the question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40149646/hide-operations-in-diagram-ea