# Hide Operations in Diagram EA

Tags: enterprise-architect

I create a model using EA Scripting. The model consists of interfaces and each interface has operations. I also add these interfaces in a composition diagram , how can I not show the operations in diagram in EA.

Is it possible by some settings in EA or I need to do it programatically

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Doing it for single elements manually is simple:

- From the context menu in the diagram choose `Features/...Visibility`
- In `Operation Visibility` click `Custom`
- Choose the operations you need to suppress

Now for the tricky part, if you need to do that for many diagrams at once. The information is stored in `t_diagram.StyleEx`. This contains a semicolon separated list of entries. One of those entries might look like

```
SPL=S_E4BB5A=69A30E,2A49EF:;
```

Now `E4BB5A` are the first 6 nibbles of the element GUID which is affected. `69A30E` and `2A49EF` are those of attributes or operations which shall be suppressed. So in order to suppress an operation on all diagrams you need to do the following:

```
oGuid = operation.methodGuid.substring(1,6) // get "69A30E" from "{69A30E-..."
eGuid = element.elementGuid.substring(1,6) // E4BB5A
sup = "SPL=S_" + eGuid + "=" + oGuid + ":;"
for dia in allDiagramsInRepos { // you need to build that on your own
  dia.styleEx += sup
  dia.update()
}
```

Of course you need to merge with existing `SPL` entries rather than simply adding them. But you should get the idea.

Comment: I dont want it to be per diagram it should not include the operations in all the diagrams while creating the diagrams in model

Comment: That would need automation. I'll answer that later the day.

Comment: See also http://sparxsystems.com/forums/smf/index.php/topic,37300.msg233927.html#msg233927